# Nested Schema referencing Nested Schema as Source of Truth

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, nosql

I am wondering how to best solve following Structure / Scenario, where we have a Nested Schema as the Source of truth and want to reference it.

Schemas:

- Game
- Contest
- Ticket with `Picks[]`

*Note: I am omitting most unnecessary fields.*

**Game**

```
var gameSchema = new Schema({
    dateTime: Date,
    location: String,
    homeTeam: String,
    awayTeam: String
});
```

**Contest**

```
var contestSchema = new Schema({
    schedule: [{
        week: Number,
        games: [gameSchema],
    }]
});
```

**Ticket with`Picks[]`**

```
var pickSchema = new Schema({
    week: Number,
    team: String,
    game: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    }
});

var ticketSchema = new Schema({
    contest: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Contest'
    },
    picks: [pickSchema]
});
```

Here are a couple of Ideas I had to solve this:

**Game Schema as its own collection**

We could move `Games` into its own collection and then simply reference the game in both `Contest` and the `Ticket.Pick`, like so `{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game'}`.

However, if I believe that I will always need `Games` when looking up `Contests`, we would want to leave the Source of truth within `Contests`, if I understand correctly.

**Skip ref, and save only the ObjectId of Games**

For this one, we would want to rewrite our `PickSchema` slightly.

```
var pickSchema = new Schema({
    week: Number,
    team: String,
    game_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId
});
```

Notice, that we are referring `Contest` on the `Ticket`. This should allow us to build something like this to the game within the `Ticket`. (Not tested, just the concept)

```
Ticket.findById(ticketObjectId).populate('contest').exec((err, tickets) => {
    let ticket = tickets[0];
    let pickedGame;

    for(pick of ticket.picks) {

        for(schedule of tickets.contest.schedule){

            if(schedule.week === pick.week) {

                for(game of schedule.games) {

                    if(game._id === pick.game_id) {
                        pickedGame = game; // Yay we found our game
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
});
```

I mean, we could pretty it up by putting above into a filter or so, but at the end of the day, this simply looks like a nightmare.

We might be able to run a query within `populate('contest')`, but after some attempts, I don't think this will give us what we are looking for.

**Duplicate Games**

Given that the scenario of games changing is relatively low. (How often does an NFL game time change e.g.) We might be able to simply put the entire game into `Contest` and `Pick`. This would mean we would have to write some rather heavy function to update every object if a game does ever change, but given that we anticipate this occurrence to be rather low, this might be an acceptable solution. However, if there is a better solution with a single source of truth, I'd rather stick with it.

**To wrap this one up**

Currently, I am tending towards moving `Games` into its own Collection and reference it across the board, this would ensure a single source of truth.